# Python move array to another one and add quotation mark?

Tags: python

Python move array to another one and add quotation mark to it. Code below

```
cars = ["ab","bc","ca"]
people = ['"ab"','"bc"','"ca"']
```

such as like that:
array cars move to people and add quotation

Comment: Sorry, I tried to understand, but the problem is unclear. What is the question? try providing some context... like, what are you trying to do? What have you tried so far? Surely giving more details it will become much easier to answer :) [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format the string with quotaiton mark and then append it to an array. e.g.

```py
    cars = ["ab","bc","ca"] 
    people = []
    for elem in cars:
        new_elem = '"{}"'.format(elem)
        people.append(new_elem)
    print(people)
```

Output:

```py
['"ab"', '"bc"', '"ca"']
```

Comment: This is simple to understand, but I would personally use the answer by @xkcdjeery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comp to do it in one line:

```py
people=['"%s"' % i for i in cars]
```